# Expressing a number as a finite sum of terms $a_k/k!$

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic

The original problem is as  - Suppose $a_2,a_3,a_4, \cdots a_7$  are integers such that

$$\frac{5}{7}=\sum_{k=2}^7 \frac{a_k}{k!}$$
where $0 \le a_j < j$ for $j=2,3,4,5,6,7$

Then find $a_2+a_3+ \dots + a_7$
This is a problem which I am unable to solve . Please help me here and also tell me about generalization of this problem . (It is OK if the solution if beyond the reach of high school students).
I  guess how to approach problems like
$$\frac{m}{n}= \sum_{k=p}^q \frac{a_k}{k!}$$ for $m,n,p,q \in \mathbb{N}$ 
for same question and condition

Comment: So the question is to prove existence of such $a_j$'s?

Comment: What is the "same question" if the original does not contain a question?

Comment: Sorry forgot the question ...I have added it

Comment: @VarunIyer: why $a_2$ can not be $0$ ?

Comment: @mesel Didn't notice the $\le$ sign. My mistake

Comment: Step 1: multiply both sides by 7-factorial, to get $$5\times6!=2520a_2+840a_3+210a_4+42a_5+7a_6+a_7$$ Then look at it modulo 7 to get $a_7$, then modulo 6, etc.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I did the modulo $7$ case ,but when I proceed with modulo $6$ case ,the answer comes in negative. Help me!

Comment: Show me, Shivam; show me what happened.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I did it modulo $7$ getting $a_7=2$ .Now when we substitute that we have $5\times6!=2520a_2+840a_3+210a_4+42a_5+7a_6+2$ looking at this modulo $6$ I have $0= a_6+2$ which is giving a problem ..Please tell me my mistake.

Comment: What you have is $a_6+2\equiv0\pmod6$, which has a unique solution with $0\le a_6<6$.

Comment: Are we OK, now, Shivam?

Comment: @GerryMyerson ....thankyou sir ,I got it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gerry Myerson has given the slick approach using modular arithmetic in the comments. There is also a more elementary approach. Suppose that the equation

$$\frac{p}q=\sum_{k=m}^n\frac{a_k}{k!}$$

has a solution in non-negative integers $a_k$ such that $a_k<k$ for $k=m,\ldots,n$. Note that

$$\sum_{k=m+1}^n\frac{k-1}{k!}=\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}\frac1{k!}-\sum_{k=m+1}^n\frac1{k!}=\frac1{m!}-\frac1{n!}<\frac1{m!}\;;$$

thus, we must set

$$a_m=\max\left\{\ell<m:\frac{\ell}{m!}\le\frac{p}q\right\}\;:$$

any larger value is clearly too large, and any smaller value leaves

$$\frac{p}q-\frac{a_m}{m!}>\frac1{m!}>\sum_{k=m+1}^n\frac{k-1}{k!}\;,$$

the maximum possible value of the sum of the remaining terms. At this point we can replace the original problem by

$$\frac{p}q-\frac{a_m}{m!}=\sum_{k=m+1}^n\frac{a_k}{k!}$$

and use exactly the same approach to find $a_{m+1}$. Continuing in this fashion, we find successively $a_m,a_{m+1},\ldots,a_n$ without guesswork at any stage. (This is in fact a [greedy algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm).)